# script is not giving correct the output in Cygwin

Tags: shell

I am facing a problem in Cygwin when I execute the below command in Unix Environment then output is coming different as compare to Cygwin

```
echo 0000036703386618|awk '{$1=$1+0; print $1}'
```

Output is in Unix

```
36703386618
```

Output is in Cygwin

```
3.67034e+10
```

Please assist

Comment: I cannot access to a `Cygwin` environment, but you could try to format `print` forcing an `integer` output using `printf()`, like: `printf "%d\n", $1`. Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Awk doesn't actually store the value as an integer, it stores it as a floating point value, so you're probably getting an output error due to the outputter being unable to display a > 32bit value in a non-scientific format (this is just a guess, but it's what happens when we switch to mawk)

```
natsu ~> echo 0000036703386618|mawk '{$1=$1+0; print $1}'
3.67034e+10
natsu ~> echo 0000036703386618|gawk '{$1=$1+0; print $1}'
36703386618
```

bear in mind that because of the internal representation of the value, it will produce some undesirable results:

```
natsu ~> echo 0000036703386618000000000|gawk '{$1=$1+0; print $1}'
36703386617999998976
```

Once you're dealing with 64bit numbers, though, you should start using something that handles them properly - e.g. bc

```
natsu ~> bc <<<"0000036703386618000000000 + 0"
36703386618000000000
```

... the prior example uses the `<<<` bash redirect to take stdin from a string/variable instead of having to do a `echo "$var" |`